# Artículo + posesivo + sustantivo en "compré cojines para 'la mi cama'". ¿Un rasgo sociolingüístico?

Tags: gramática, coloquialismos, dialectos, posesivos, guatemala

Recién tuve una conversación por WhatsApp con una amiga. Ella es de Guatemala, clase media y con formación académica, y en un momento de la conversación usó la siguiente estructura:

> Compré dos cojines para ***la mi cama***.

Mi duda es: ¿fue esto un sencillo error o es en realidad esta estructura *artículo + posesivo + sustantivo* un rasgo característico de determinados dialectos/sociolectos del español?

Comment: Un sencillo error, diría yo.  La mayoría de los errores sintácticos surgen, en mi experiencia, porque el autor empezó a hacer una sustitución, pero se olvidó de borrar todo el texto original.

Comment: Sé que hay zonas que mantienen uso de esta estructura (que aún es regla en otros idiomas que vienen de latín), y que en ellas es más fuerte su empleo con artículos indefinidos, pero no es estrictamente incorrecto. Ahora, si no pertenece al dialecto de ella, sería error

Answer (score 2):

El capítulo 18 de la *Nueva Gramática* habla sobre el tema largo y tendido a partir del [párrafo 18.2i](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=buPQJHKKQtDSSBIO):

> Los posesivos pronominales ocupan en español la posición de los determinantes, a diferencia de otras lenguas románicas como el catalán (*la seva casa lit. 'la su casa' ~ **seva casa*) o el italiano (il suo amico lit. 'el su amigo' ~ **suo amico*). [...] Se dice, *{el ~ este ~ mi ~ algún}* libro*, pero no **el mi perro, *algún su amigo, *un mi coche, *muchos sus problemas*, etc.

Pero pronto empieza a dar contraejemplos, como en expresiones de carácter formal:

> Tan grata nueva la hemos celebrado en esta su casa.
>
> En aquella mi sexta mañana de soledar en el mar, pensé que todo eso estaba ocurriendo.

Y es porque en el español medieval y el clásico su uso se atestigua ampliamente:

> Dize el Almirante que aquella su navegación avía sudo muy cierta y que avía carteado bien.
>
> Oh señora de mi alma, Dulcinea, flor de la fermosura, socorred a este vuestro caballero.

Comenta el párrafo 18.2j que

> La combinación «demostrativo + posesivo» presenta varios usos en el español actual. En algunas zonas del área andina pertenece a la lengua estándar, incluso a la conversacional: *Como yo había criado a esta mi hermanita desde que nació, eso me causó un sufrimiento muy grande*.

Sin embargo, el uso de tu amiga fue el de un «artículo definido + posesivo». Para esto nos vamos al párrafo 18.2l:

> El posesivo se podía combinar [en la lengua antigua] con los artículos definido e indefinido, así como con los demostrativos, numerales cardinales y cuantificadores existenciales y evaluativos.

Y comenta una serie de pautas, la primera de las cuales es:

> A. «Artículo definido + posesivo»: *Mas yo uençunda tiendo los mis reales braços a los tos ynoios*.

Se ha ido a coger el ejemplo a un texto de Alfonso X: *General Estoria II*, que es del siglo XIII. Pero bueno, de esta pauta dice que fue cayendo en desuso, aunque pervivió en las hablas septentrionales y noroccidentales de la Península Ibérica, en las que todavía se registran: *Y a too y a esto, finuca ella; finuco el su andar; finuco el su vestir, aunque el vestío sea probo*.

Sobre la pauta B, que es similar pero con los artículos indefinidos, dice (negritas mías):

> [...] se documenta hoy en la misma área. También **se registra** en México, en particular en el estado de Chiapas, así como **en varios países centroamericanos, especialmente Guatemala, Nicaragua y El Salvador**.

Y cita los siguientes ejemplos:

> Cabe señalar que los desconocedores en materia de montañismo suelen pensar que llega uno con un su grupo y sube de inmediato a la montaña (Torres Nava, *Conquista*).
>
> Se fue quedando en los huesos, el pobre, con una su mirada como de chucho triste (Flores, *Siguamonta*).
>
> Fumó, sin aprender, unos sus cigarritos y empezó a leer, por exigencias del estudio, la teoría de la plusvalía (Flores, *Siguamonta*).
>
> Se le entrega un su cochito o una su ovejita o unas sus dos gallinitas (Burgos, E. *Rigoberta*).

Afirma la *Gramática* que es muy probable que "esta pauta muestre simplemente la pervivencia de la antigua construcción castellana". En el caso de tu amiga no se usa un artículo indeterminado, sino uno determinado. Sin embargo, si está acostumbrada a la construcción "un su", no sería raro que usara también una del tipo "la su".